# Converting UTM to decimal degrees with st_transform (a southern hemisphere error)

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, r-sf

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

x <- 500000
y <- 4649776
zone_num <- "33"
ellipsoid <- "WGS84"
res <- data.frame(x, y) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"),
               crs = paste0("+proj=utm +zone=", zone_num)) %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = paste0("+proj=longlat +datum=", ellipsoid)) %>%
  sf::st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename("lon" = "X", "lat" = "Y");res

# Test case 2: Southern hemisphere
x2 <- 500000
y2 <- (4649776 +10000000)-1 # +10000000)-1 tp adjust for southern hemisphere latitude
res <- data.frame(x2, y2) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x2", "y2"),
               crs = paste0("+proj=utm +zone=", zone_num)) %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = paste0("+proj=longlat +datum=", ellipsoid)) %>%
  sf::st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename("lon" = "X", "lat" = "Y");res
```

For the first the output is correct
lon: 15
lat: 42

For the southern hemisphere it incorrect as it should be
lon: 15
lat: -48.30

but the output is this:
lon: -165
lat: 48.2686

I don't understand why this is happening, the longitude should be unchanged, and the latitude is nearly 0.04 degrees off. Any idea why sf is having trouble transforming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues here. The main one is that your `proj4string` for the southern hemisphere [should have](https://proj.org/en/9.2/operations/projections/utm.html#cmdoption-arg-south) the `+south` parameter.

The second issue is that the [Northing range in UTM](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/c2_p23.html#:%7E:text=UTM%20eastings%20range%20from%20167%2C000,10%2C000%2C000%20meters%20in%20South%20zones.) is between 0 and around 10 million. You are adding 10 million to your original Northing (`y`) value so you end up with a number outside the valid range.

If you fix these issues you will get the same `lon` value as in the northern hemisphere and the appropriate `lat` value:

```r
x2 <- x
y2 <- (y + 5e6) - 1 # only adding 5m
data.frame(x2, y2) %>%
    sf::st_as_sf(
        coords = c("x2", "y2"),
        crs = paste0("+proj=utm +zone=", zone_num, " +south") # Note " + south"
    ) %>%
    sf::st_transform(crs = paste0("+proj=longlat +datum=", ellipsoid)) %>%
    sf::st_coordinates() %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    dplyr::rename("lon" = "X", "lat" = "Y")


#   lon       lat
# 1  15 -3.168563
```

Comment: Adding the south parameter is great and fixed my issue! I no longer need to transform the y axis by adding false northing values and multiplying by -1. Thank you!